# Problem about recursive dict creation in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I've seen this bit of code online:

```
class StreamChecker(object):
    def __init__(self, words):
        """
        :type words: List[str]
        """
        print(words)
        self.waitlist = []
        self.trie = dict()
        for word in words:
            temp_dict = self.trie
            for letter in word:
                temp_dict = temp_dict.setdefault(letter, dict())

            temp_dict['#'] = '#'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = StreamChecker(['abc', 'wef', 'ykj'])
    print(a.trie)
```

After initiation, print `self.trie` gets `{'a': {'b': {'c': {'#': '#'}}}, 'w': {'e': {'f': {'#': '#'}}}, 'y': {'k': {'j': {'#': '#'}}}}`

I'm confused about this line `'temp_dict = temp_dict.setdefault(letter, dict())'` in the code. As every time `setdefault` will return an empty dict `{}`, why `self.trie` is changed every time since `setdefault` is only used upon an empty dict? To my understanding, `self.trie` will only be changed once for every `word` and `self.trie` should be like `{'a': {}, 'w': {}, 'y': {}}`

Can someone explain this to me? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> help(dict.setdefault)
setdefault(self, key, default=None, /)
    Insert key with a value of default if key is not in the dictionary.

    Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default.
```

One empty dict is not necessarily the same object as another empty dict. What's happening is that the line

```
temp_dict = temp_dict.setdefault(letter, dict())
```

is first adding a new key to the current `temp_dict` (with the corresponding value being an empty dict), and then returning *the reference to that newly-added value*. When it gets run in the loop, it ends up recursively adding new dictionaries to whatever the original was (that is, `self.trie`).

Because the nested `dict` we're modifying is contained within `self.trie`, we can see our change reflected in `self.trie`.

---

It might help to decompose this statement:

```
temp_dict = temp_dict.setdefault(letter, dict())
```

into this:

```
if letter not in temp_dict:
    temp_dict[letter] = dict()  # create a new dict, and put it inside the current dict
temp_dict = temp_dict[letter]   # jump inside the new dict that we just created, 
                                # or the existing dict that was there if it already existed.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've read the documentation about `setdefault()` and it only says return the default value if the key is not in the dict, and it doesn't specify it is a reference. I tried to check the type of temp_dict and it only says dictionary. So is there a way to tell if a dict is a reference to another dict or not? Will this happen to other data structures like list or tuple? Many thanks!

Comment: @WenbinXu *Everything* is a reference. Every variable of every type is a reference to some data stored somewhere. We usually cut out the middleman when talking about references and just refer to the data the references point at, to simplify our discussions. The thing to understand here is that you can have two identical `dict`s that are not the same object (just as you can have two identical objects sitting next to each other in real life - they're not the same object, they just behave the same way).

Comment: A `list` or `dict` can contain anything. In the case of `dict`, both the keys and the values are references to data - that data can be whatever you want. It's possible for a list or dict to contain itself, though you probably shouldn't do that. Or it can contain a *different* list/dict, which is what's happening here. That, in turn, can contain other stuff, and so on ad infinitum.